# How to add a link in Dropdown in drupal

Tags: forms, commerce, javascript, ajax

I have some addresses in Dropdown list and now i want to add "Add new Adrress" link along with my Addresses in dropdown.And on link click i want to open cTools popup for form elements.how can i achieve this,please help.

```
$form['line_items'][$line_item_id]['default_address'] = array(
'#title' => 'Send To',
'#type' => 'select',
'#default_value' => $defualt_profile,
'#options' => $last_5_profile,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the  [Better Jump Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_jump_menu) module.

> Better Jump Menu is a module who provides:
>
> - The Drupal menu blocks with menu links in a select box instead of a    list.
> - A Views style plugins to display links into a select box.
> - It can display any entity field in a select list, see features below.

Similar module [Better Jump Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/jump_menu)

[image]